# .ipa install over the air

Tags: ios, ipa, over-the-air

Is it possible to have any url in the `manifest.plist`, for the feedback to know if the **.ipa** is installed on the device by the url or I have to write that call in the app?

I know about Crashlytics, and such apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`manifest.plist` does not provide this callback, you can implement it in your App as you mentioned.

Or you can get the download completed event from the HTTP server which hosts the `.ipa`